# .is() jQuery - como funciona?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como funciona a função .is() em jQuery, eu vi ela sendo usada em um código, no código tem uma variável $lastClicked, declarada, depois é feita uma comparação (!$(this).is($lastClicked)), só que eu não entendi como .is() funciona, e qual a finalidade do $lastClicked no código! se alguém puder responder - agradeço.

O código é o seguinte:

```js
// Apenas parte do código ...
$(function(){
    var $lastClicked;
    function onTarefaItemClick(){
        if(!$(this).is($lastClicked)){
            if($lastClicked !== undefined){
                savePendingEdition($lastClicked);
            }
            $lastClicked = $(this);
            var text = $lastClicked.children('.tarefa-texto').text();
            var html = '<input type="text" class="tarefa-edit" value="' + text + '">';
            $lastClicked.html(html);
            $('.tarefa-edit').keydown(onTarefaEditKeydown);
        }
    }
    $('.tarefa-item').click(onTarefaItemClick);
    function onTarefaEditKeydown(event){
        if(event.which === 13){
            savePendingEdition($lastClicked);
            $lastClicked = undefined;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) do JQuery serve para verificar se o elemento selecionado corresponde a um determinado elemento.

Esta função pode ser chamada passando parâmetros diferentes:

- Seletor
- Objeto
- Função

### Passando um seletor

Quando passa um seletor o `is` verifica se o elemento que tem corresponde ao seletor passado. Um exemplo simples disto seria `$(this).is(".premiado")` que verifica se o elemento corrente, o `$(this)` corresponde à classe `premiado`. É importante mencionar que o seletor pode ser bem mais elaborado incluindo todo o tipo de seletores suportados tanto em JQuery como em CSS3.

Exemplo de `is` com base numa classe:

```js
$("li").on("click", function(){
  if ($(this).is(".premiado")){
    console.log("li premiado!"); 
  }
  else {
    console.log("li normal");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Clique nos vários li's
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li class="premiado">3 (premiado)</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
 </ul>
```

### Passando um Objeto

Também é possível verificar se um elemento corresponde a outro que você tem guardado num objeto. Isto regra geral implica que previamente guardou numa variável um elemento com algo como `let elemento = $(this);` e depois mais à frente testa se corresponde fazendo `$(...).is(elemento)`.

Com a passagem de um objeto é fácil de montar um exemplo que lhe diga se clicou no ultimo elemento ou num diferente:

```js
let ultimo;
$("li").on("click", function(){
  if ($(this).is(ultimo)){
    console.log("li é o mesmo que o anterior"); 
  }
  else {
    console.log("li diferente");
  }
  ultimo = $(this); //o ultimo passa a ser este elemento
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Clique nos vários li's, e mais que uma vez no mesmo
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
 </ul>
```

### Passando Função

Embora bem menos comum é também possível de passar uma função que lhe indica se corresponde ou não ao elemento. O corresponder é feito através do que a função retorna, sendo que verdadeiro faz o `is` corresponder e falso faz não corresponder. Nesta função pode implementar qualquer lógica que pretenda.

Normalmente esta forma toma o seguinte aspeto:

```
if ($(this).is(function(){
    //função para avaliar se é ou não retornando um booleano
}){
    //código para executar quando é   
}
```

Exemplo de um `is` que verifica se o elemento clicado corresponde a um que tenha um texto especifico:

```js
$("li").on("click", function(){
  if ($(this).is(function(){
    return $(this).text() == "5";
  })){
    console.log("li com texto 5"); 
  }
  else {
    console.log("li com texto diferente de 5");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Clique nos vários li's
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
 </ul>
```

Neste caso também pode utilizar uma [*Arrow Function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) para simplificar o código da função, transformando-o em:

```
if ($(this).is(() => $(this).text() == "5"){
    console.log("li com texto 5"); 
}
```

### Código mostrado na pergunta

Se olhar para o código que tem na pergunta e para o meu exemplo de passar um objeto vai ver que é o mesmo. O código que verifica se o elemento clicado é diferente do ultimo que foi clicado:

```
if(!$(this).is($lastClicked)){
```

Irá fazer varias coisas e guardar o ultimo clicado como o corrente:

```
$lastClicked = $(this);
```

Também guarda as alterações caso exista um último (primeira que clica não tem ultimo):

```
if($lastClicked !== undefined){
    savePendingEdition($lastClicked);
```

Answer (score 4):

A função [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) do `jQuery` é usado para verificar se um objeto "bate" com um determinado seletor.

Veja esse exemplo:

```js
console.log("O elemento 'i' é um input: " + $('#i').is('input'));
console.log("O elemento 'i' é um input text: " + $('#i').is('input[type=text]'));
console.log("O elemento 'i' é um input radio: " + $('#i').is('input[type=radio]'));

console.log("O elemento 'c' é um input: " + $('#c').is('input'));
console.log("O elemento 'c' é um input text: " + $('#c').is('input[type=text]'));
console.log("O elemento 'c' é um input checkbox: " + $('#c').is('input[type=checkbox]'));
console.log("O elemento 'c' é um input checkbox e está checado: " + $('#c').is('input[type=checkbox]:checked'));
console.log("O elemento 'c' é um input checkbox e não está checado: " + !$('#c').is('input[type=checkbox]:checked'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="i" type="text" />
<input id="c" type="checkbox" />
```

No exemplo, o `is()` é usando para comparar o elemento com vários seletores, verificando se o elemento "bate" com cada um deles, se **é** como um dos seletores.

Para esclarecer quanto ao exemplo de código da pergunta, o propósito provavelmente é saber se o elemento que foi clicado é ou não o mesmo que foi clicado anteriormente. Veja que a variável `$lastClicked` ou é setada como `undefined`, com com `$(this)`, ou seja, algum elemento clicado. No início da function, verifica `if(!$(this).is($lastClicked))`, ou seja, se o elemento clicado (`this`) não é o último elemento que clicado anteriormente (`$lastClicked`).

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra visão é que o que o .is() faz é verificar se o objeto verificado $("x") corresponde ao seletor .is("y") informado, retornando um booleano.

Na pratica eu costumo utilizá-lo apenas para verificar estados dos elementos, exemplos:

Verificar se uma div está oculta:

```
var divEstaOculta = $("#minhDiv").is(":hidden");
```

Verificar se um input está desabilitado:

```
var estaDesabilitado = $("#meuInput").is(":disabled");
```

Verificar se um checkbox está checkado:

```
var estaCheckado = $("#meuCheckbox").is(":checked");
```

Mas também é retornado true, quando você compara com alguma propriedade do objeto, exemplo:

```
<div id="meuId" class="minhaClasse" ></div>

$("#meuId").is(".minhaClasse") // true
```